# Failure to display the output despite entering the codes

Tags: python, html, django, categories

Despite entering the codes, no output is displayed in this field.
What is the reason?

in views.py:

```py
def category(request, category_id):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=category_id)
    products = category.product_set.all()
    return render(request, 'category.html', {'category': category, 'products': products})
```

in urls.py:

```py
path("category<int:category_id>", views.category, name="category")
```

in category.html:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
{% block body %}

<h2>{{ category.name }}</h2>
<ul>
    {% for product in products %}
        <li>{{ product.category }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

in layout.html(To display the categories when you click on it.):

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Auctions{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'auctions/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Auctions</h1>
        <div>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                Signed in as <strong>{{ user.username }}</strong>.
            {% else %}
                Not signed in.
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Active Listings</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                {% for category in categories %}
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'category' category.id %}">Category</a>
                {% endfor%}
            </li>

            

            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
        <hr>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

A title should be created in the layout to display all the categories by clicking on it.

Comment: In *what* field, does your `layout.html` has a `body` block?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem  On the site page, it displays the linked titles.
I modified the code.

Comment: Is it the missing content in `category.html` or no links generated in `layout.html`?

Comment: But what does `layout` then do? It seems to define no block, and fill no block either.

Comment: @ willeM_Van Onsem  I just wrote the code for this part.
This file has about 50 lines of code.

Comment: @oq In the console, the name of the category written in the layout is not read and the name of the category that should be displayed on the screen is not displayed.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, for generating caregory links in the `layout.html`, you need to add `categories` into the context on the `views.py`. Other one is like @willeM_VanOnsem mentioned, you need to wrap those `<li>...</li>` in the `layout.html` in `{% block body %}`, like this: `{% block body %}<li>...</li>{% endblock %}`.

Comment: @oq I had written the file briefly. I wrote it completely now. Please check the question again.